# Grant user access to List View but not list

Tags: permissions, list-view, custom-list

I would like to create a view for a list so that users can load this view and see all of the results in it without having access to the underlying list. Basically the view has a filter in it and I only want them to be able to access those items.

Is this possible?

Edit: To expand further based on feedback from answers:

Basically we have an order management system with 2 main suppliers. An order comes in and will only be allocated to one of these suppliers. Is is possible to give each supplier access to orders that are flagged as theirs only? I think in the end what we're going to do is use the API to provide a view to them and handle the authentication for the list not in SharePoint.

Comment: Hopefully Chris answered your question but to me your request requires a bit more clarity. > Blockquote users can load this view and see all of the results in it without having access to the underlying list could you please clarify what you want users to see, and what you don't want them to have access to? and please specify what level of access you are concerned with the user having? In order for a user to see a list item he/she must have at least "read" access to the list item but that does not mean they have access to modify items or make changes to the list settings. As Chris mentioned, yo

Comment: Hi Tal, I've extended my question with some more detail. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Views can security trim, limiting users to only seeing the items they have permissions to, but they cannot have their own permission sets. Basically you have a few options:

1. Apply item level permissions so users only see the appropriate items they have permissions to. Item level permissions are tricky to manage however, and have both performance implications and some hard limits on # of items that can be secured.
2. If the # of permission sets to grant are well-known, create folders for each permission set and apply permissions on the folder instead of the individual items. You can turn off Folders in Views, so your users don't even really have to understand that folders are in use, but you will need a workflow or other strategy for how new items can placed into the correct folders.
3. Develop a custom web part (farm trust only) that can use elevated permissions in code to access items the user does not have direct access to. You can code the web part to render a particular view, so you can still use view capabilities to determine what the web part shows (based on filters, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I took so long to reply. I had written a long reply on my mobile and lost reception so the text was never submitted. So this reply will be shorter :-)

If you have the orders in two different lists you can achieve this of course

If all items need to be in the same list you can have a folder for each supplier, with security applied to the folder, so when the suppler opens the list the items they dont have access to will be security trimmed.

Of course you could apply security manually to each item (definitely not recommended)

The second option has one drawback, when a user creates an order they need to make sure to put it in the correct folder, leaving you open to user error. To make this simpler for users you could make a new field in the list called "supplier" which would be a choice between supplier A and supplier B. You then would create a workflow on the list which would run when an item is created. The workflow would then be responsible for putting the item in the correct folder.

If you have not yet found your answer I hope this helps. Please mark this as answered if this has helped you.

Tal