# How to grant access to a list view but not to entire list

Tags: permissions, list-view, accessibility

We have some views to our list, while each view reveals a specific columns.
We want to grant (RO) access to a view without granting access to all list data.

Is this possible?

(I already examined the answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72186/grant-user-access-to-list-view-but-not-list), but that doesn't answers my question)

Answer (score 3):

The linked answer, does answer your question indeed.
The gist is: you cannot assign per-view permissions. Permissions are assignable either at a whole list level or single item level.

Having said that, what I'm going to show you is a workaround I found myself using more than a few times:

**WARNING**: this is by no means a security restriction. All the data will still be accessible to the users with read permission. You are just making harder for them to find a way to get the data you have hidden from them, but a determined user will eventually find a way to see all the list and in no way you can avoid this, unless you resort to denying access altogether to the list and surfacing it through custom server side code.

1. go to your library AllItems.aspx view. Edit the page, then close the webpart. Optionally (I usually do this), add a content editor web part with a javascript to redirect (`windows.location.href`) somewhere else (eg. the homepage)
2. if you don't have one yet, create a Pages library.
3. create a page for each view you need to assign specific permissions to.
4. edit each page and add a webpart showing one of the views.
5. set each page to stop inheriting permissions, then assign the specific permissions according to your per-view criterion
6. create a page, name it eg. AllItems, add a webpart and show the list all items view. Stop inheriting permissions and assign full control to you and everyone you need to have full control/contribute control to the list.

In this way, none but you and someone with the proper permissions can access the "all items" view, and you can give different permissions to all the other views you created for the list.

Comment: Good answer, +1, but the OP needs to clearly understand this approach is not securing the data, it is merely obfuscating it.  A smart, highly motivated user armed with a search engine will figure out a way to view that data, and there really isn't a way to block that short of restricting access to the list and surfacing the desired data through custom server-side code.  Depending on the nature of the data and the strictness of the requirement, this may or may not be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I re-read my answer and edited to make it clearer that, as you rightly said, this is not a security restriction.

Comment: I had the use this method also. I ended up restricting the view completely and use pages to show data.

Answer (score 0):

The only other option is to create custom code that executes under a RunWithElevatedPriveledges block to fetch the data the user normally wouldn't have access to and not grant the users access to the list.